# basic math inside mySQL query loop with updates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out if I can do some math completely within mySQL (5.1) but am not 
sure if this is possible.  I am not an expert with SQL.

I have two tables.  One to track overall time, and one with individiual time entries.
The idea is to keep a running total in Table1 based on what was used in Table2.

Table1:

```
UserID (INT),
TotalTime (INT)
```

Table2:

```
UserID (INT),
TimeUsed (INT),
isCalculated (bool)
```

What I would like to do is iterate through Table 2 where isCalculated is false and 
subtract the Table2.TimeUsed for each entry from the Table1.TotalTime where Table1.UserID=Table2.UserID.

After the calculation I would need to toggle isCalculated to true.

It seems this could be done in a loop, but I am not sure of the proper syntax in mySQL.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: What is your current mysql code? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: You join the tables to do the calculation, but we need more information.

Comment: Thanks for the code edit Nelson.  Part of my problem is I don't know what mySQL functionality would be used to do this.  In Delphi, I could just do this with a couple datasets and a FOR loop.  I'm stuck at how to begin writing the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    Table1
    JOIN Table2 ON Table1.UserID = Table2.UserID
SET
    Table1.TotalTime = Table1.TotalTime - Table2.TimeUsed,
    Table2.isCalculated = TRUE
WHERE
    NOT Table2.isCalculated
```

Comment: Perfect, this is 'exactly' what I needed.  Thank you!